# A script that deletes the exe or file after completion

Tags: powershell

So I turned a PowerShell script into a executable but at the end of the script it should delete itself but it doesn't. Any ideas?

`Remove-Item C:\Test.exe -Force` just won't auto delete after it finishes.

Comment: Just for background information, why do create an exe and not just use .ps1 file?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this can work, because the executable should delete itself while it is running, though it works with .ps1. I would suggest the following:

1. Run the executable
2. Last step of exe is to run another script that is deleting the exe

or use .ps1 instead of an exe..